# Is there any structure in general on the $p$th cohomotopy set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, universal-algebra

The $p$th [cohomotopy **set**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomotopy_group) of a pointed space $X$, $\pi^p(X)$, is the set of maps from $X$ to $S^p$ mod pointed homotopy. Unlike homotopy, there need be no natural group structure on $\pi^p(X)$ unless ($X$ is particularly nice or) $p\in\{0,1,3,7\}$: if $p$ is one of these values then we can use the group structure on $S^p$ to "add maps pointwise" *(EDIT: it's not a group at $p=7$, since octonion multiplication isn't associative, but it's still algebraically nontrivial)* but [otherwise no such group structure exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081454/concerning-adams-theorem-binary-continous-operation-on-spheres).

At this point it's natural to ask whether we can still find *some* algebraic structure on $\pi^p(X)$ if $p\not\in\{0,1,3,7\}$ (and $X$ is not particularly nice). Unfortunately, Adams' theorem can be strengthened: [Walter Taylor showed](https://eudml.org/doc/212454) that in a precise sense there is no nontrivial ("demanding") algebraic structure on $S^p$ at all for $p\not\in\{0,1,3,7\}$.

My question is whether this is lethal:

> Is there some $p\not\in \{0,1,3,7\}$ such that there exists some natural algebraic structure on $\pi^p(X)$ for arbitrary $X$ *(or at least for $X$ substantially more general than suspensions)*?

By "algebraic structure" I really intend to cast a wide net, hence the universal algebra tag. One possible precisiation of the question would be the following: letting $\tau$ be the "obvious" topology on $\pi^p(X)$, is there in the sense of Taylor's paper a nontrivial algebraic structure on $\pi^p(X)$ compatible with $\tau$? However, I'm also open to other reasonable interpretations.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit naive, but can't we "reverse" the construction of the group structure on $\pi_p(X)$ to get some sort of "co-multiplication" on $\pi^p(X)$, using the natural $S^p\to S^p\wedge S^p$?

Comment: Nice question! In the first paragraph, by "group structure on $S^p$" you meant Moufang loop structure? Or does "group" mean something else in this context?

Comment: @pregunton Whoops, it's only a group for 0,1,3 - for 7 it's not associative. Fixing ...

Comment: @CaptainLama That map is null homotopic so will give trivial structure.

Comment: Well, there is a "universal" algebraic structure you can give, which just consists of all finitary operations on $S^p$ (in the pointed homotopy category).  But maybe you want something more concrete than this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am surprised that the wikipedia article does not mention the cohomotopy groups which were invented by Borsuk in 1936. They are not defined for arbitrary $X$, but if $X$ is a *CW-complex of dimension $\le 2n-2$*, then you get the structure of an abelian group on $\pi^n(X)$. This is also true for any *metric space of dimension $\le 2n-2$*.

See

Borsuk, K. "Sur les groupes des classes de transformations continues." CR Acad. Sci. Paris 202.1400-1403 (1936): 2.

Borsuk, Karol. Theory of retracts. Vol. 44. Państwowe Wydawn. Naukowe, 1967. [Here Chapter II Section 11.]

Hilton, Peter. "On some contributions of Karol Borsuk to homotopy theory." Topological Methods in Nonlinear Analysis 1.1 (1993): 9-14.

https://www.tmna.ncu.pl/static/files/v01n1-03.pdf

Spanier, E.H. "Borsuk's cohomotopy groups." Annals of Mathematics (1949): 203-245.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969362?seq=1

Borsuk, Karol. "On a generalization of the cohomotopy groups." Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Ser. Sci. Math. Astr. Phys 8 (1960): 615-620.

Comment: This is quite neat - thanks!